# #include <ESP8266WiFi.h> Error with WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.h

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide

I am new to the Arduino world and it seems that this simple problem is keeping me at the start line.

- I use the Generic ESP8266 Module as Board
- In my sketch I just write:

```cpp
#include < ESP8266WiFi.h >
void setup(){}
void loop(){}
```

The **ERROR** is :

BearSSLHelpers.h:148:34: error: 'virtual const unsigned char* BearSSL::HashSHA256::oid()' marked override, but does not override

```cpp
 virtual const unsigned char *oid() override;

                              ^
```

How am I going to solve that? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: with esp8266 Arduino core 2.5.2 I can compile it without errors

Comment: Well, I can't..

Comment: Installed the ESP8266 Arduino core 2.5.2 and tried to run this simple code above

Comment: 1) File > Preferences  and on Additional Boards Manager URLs i pasted
http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json


2)  Tools > Board > Board Manager > typed "ESP8266" and installed ESP8266 by ESP8266 Community version 2.5.2

Comment: there is `virtual const void *hash() override` on line 148 in release

Comment: Thank you. But what I have to do to fix this?

Comment: how did you get parts of the git version? did you download and install the library separately? delete it from your libraries folder

Comment: Ok after deleting the library folder from my libraries folder it worked!
Thank you so much!

So just to get this straight, when I install a library, I don't have to have the library folder in my Arduino > libraries folder ??

Comment: not the libraries which are part of the boards package

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed the latest git version of the ESP8266WiFi library into your libraries folder and this version is not compatible with the 2.5.2 version of the esp82666 Arduino core.

The ESP8266WiFi library is part of the esp8266 boards package. It should not be installed separately. Delete the library from your libraries folder.